# Как в HTML5 задать расположение (в моём случае логотипы социальных сетей) в одну строку без использования css и js?

Tags: html5

Как в HTML5 задать расположение (в моём случае логотипы социальных сетей) в одну строку без использования css и js ?
Пробовал как на скрине, не вышло.

```
<footer>
  <h2>Свяжитесь со мной</h2>
  <div style="display: inline-block;">
    <p>
      <a title="Одноклассники" href="#"><img src="img/ok.png" alt="иконка Одноклассники" width="30px" height="30px"></a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <a title="Телеграм" href="#"><img src="img/tg.png" alt="иконка Телеграм" width="30px" height="30px"></a>
    </p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: `display: inline-flex`

Comment: Замени картинку текстом кода.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы расположить картинки в линию, вам нужно чтобы "рядом друг с другом" лежали инлайновые элементы (в вашем случае это `<a>`), т.е. получается `<p>` тут будет лишний.

```html
<footer>
  <h2>Свяжитесь со мной</h2>
  <div style="display: inline-block;">
    <a title="Одноклассники" href="#"><img src="//i.imgur.com/eqXzEK4.png" alt="иконка Одноклассники" width="30px" height="30px"></a>
    <a title="Телеграм" href="#"><img src="//i.imgur.com/2ag7ICB.png" alt="иконка Телеграм" width="30px" height="30px"></a>
  </div>
</footer>
```